# Quick question about MutableLiveData (android)

Tags: android, mutablelivedata

Inside main activity, i cannot call getValue() on a MutableLiveData attribute of a ViewModel; however, i can inside the ViewModel class. What is the reason for this?

Example code: Main Activity -

```
noodleViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoodleViewModel.class);
        noodleViewModel.indexOfItemSelected.observe(this, index ->
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, String.format("This is the index: %d", index.intValue()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        );
```

Inside ViewModel class -

```
   public int getPosition() {
        return indexOfItemSelected.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already observing your LiveData, so `index` parameter of your lambda is already the value you are looking for

```
noodleViewModel.indexOfItemSelected.observe(this, index -> {
    index == noodleViewModel.indexOfItemSelected.getValue() // should return true
}
```